# How to discard already rendered views in Yii

Tags: php, yii, error-handling

I have an error handler function, which is binded like this:

```
Yii::app()->attachEventHandler('onError',array($this,'handleError'));
Yii::app()->attachEventHandler('onException',array($this,'handleError'));
```

Now this function renders a view with description of the error:

```
public function handleError(CEvent $event) {
    // simplified
    $event->handled = true;
    $this->render("/main/error");
}
```

However, often part of the view is already rendered, and this does not discard that - actually, it renders the error view INTO the old view, which causes broken HTML and layout.

Is there a way to discard what has already been rendered, and continue with clean page?

I tried `ob_end_clean()` but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Screw it, stupid Yii.

Won't risk another Tumbleweed.

The trick is to use

```
while (@ob_end_clean()) {}
```

Because there are apparently multiple buffers used.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you I have an idea:

Create private variable in the class your handler belongs to, eg.:

```
private $_errorCaught = false;
```

and in your handler add check for it:

```
public function handleError(CEvent $event) {
    // simplified
    $event->handled = true;
    // if we didn't get any error
    if(!$this->_errorCaugth)
    {
        $this->_errorCaught = true;
        $this->render("/main/error");
    }
    else
        $this->renderPartial("/main/error");
}
```

Another variant: redirect to error page.